# VB.Net threading advice

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have datagrid with some data and I'm making a loop through the items with for... next
Inside the loop i'm making a call to a web service with parameters from the datagrid
Because of the speed the work is very time consuming and I want to give the user the option to select how many multiple calls to the service he want.
How can I make simultaneously calls to the web service inside the loop?

Comment: How are you doing your calls right now? Same way, but inside each thread. You may need to create a new channel every time. Another thing - don't send data from the data grid, this is inefficient, from the maintenance standpoint. Use an underlying data source, such as a data table, or its descendant class. Then you can have strong typed members, no need for casting and less error prone.

Comment: This very rarely works, web services have counter-measures against clients hogging their resources.  They will either handle only one request at a time or put you on the black-list so you can't use the service anymore.  Work with the service provider to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want so here's an example using the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) class. The key point is to iterate the underlying data source (read only) inside the background thread. When finished, move back to the UI thread and update.

```vb
Private Sub BeginAsyncOp(list As IList)

    Static cachedSource As CancellationTokenSource
    Static cachedId As Long

    If ((Not cachedSource Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not cachedSource.IsCancellationRequested)) Then
        cachedSource.Cancel()
    End If

    cachedSource = New CancellationTokenSource
    cachedId += 1L

    Dim token As CancellationToken = cachedSource.Token
    Dim id As Integer = cachedId

    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        Sub()

            Dim result As IList = Nothing
            Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing
            Dim cancelled As Boolean = False

            Try

                'Background thread, do not make any UI calls.

                For Each item In list
                    '...
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(True)
                Next

                result = a_updated_list

            Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
                cancelled = True
            Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
                cancelled = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                [error] = ex
            Finally
                If (id = cachedId) Then
                    Me.Invoke(
                        Sub()
                            If (((Not Me.IsDisposed) AndAlso (Not Me.Disposing))) Then

                               'UI thread.

                                If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then
                                    '...
                                ElseIf (Not cancelled) Then
                                    For Each item In result
                                        '...
                                    Next
                                End If

                            End If
                        End Sub)
                End If
            End Try

        End Sub)

End Sub
```